# Missing assembly reference when building with MSBuild but build success in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, nant

I'm trying to create nAnt build scripts for our project.
When I try to build it via msbuild - called from nAnt as an external task, i got the whole loads of missing reference errors. But when I try to build it from the VS 2008 it's OK.
I've found one project which is referencing (by "using" clause in the *.cs file by an namespace below) to another webproject. The point is that this WebProject is called WebClient in SLN but in it's properities get's also the output assembly with other namespace like Copmany.Something.dll. I've tried to add reference to it by pointing it from VS but VS does not allow me to do that because it would be a circular dependency. 
Maybe someone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call **MSBuild.exe** from [VS command promt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx). Command line has the same biuld environment as VS. To make it work from the script or CI you can call **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat**.

**EDIT:**
You can build your sln files:

```
MSBuild.exe 1.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"
```

If you can be sure that VS builds Sln without errors, you can set the same build behavouir in nant.

Comment: I've forgot about this option but, in my case it's not working, besides I discover one more thing, there are two SLN files, and it seems that some projects from 1st SLN are reffering to the 2nd one. Strange but when building this solution via VS there are no errors.

Comment: Problem solved. The main base reference error giving problem was inproper usage of references, and "meesed up" name spaces in hose two SLN's. I had to refactor those two solutions and after that it's building without problem.

Comment: @Sergio Rykov, I tried the step you suggested. I am getting same errors as I am getting on using MSBuild task of NAnt. The are huge numbers of missing assembly errors. When I use VS, its compiling successfully. What should I do? Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it turned out to be caused by NAnt targeting the 4.0 runtime. Visual Studio was targeting 3.5, so the dependencies were handled differently, I guess. I fixed it by forcing NAnt to target the 3.5 runtime.

```
<property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5" />
```